# Unity3D player not dying after bullet prefab hitting him despite collision being logged & checkpoint being saved

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My game is a Unity3D game. The player has 2 colliders on him, a character controller and a Character Controller (in retrospect should have been Rigidbody). There are enemies in the game who shoot bullets as projectiles at the player. For some reason, the player is not 'dying' when the bullet hits him. It is set so that the player teleports to a checkpoint saved in the GameManager script upon being hit by a bullet, or rather that the bullet teleports the player to the last checkpoint saved in the GameManager script after hitting the player. Here is the function in the bullet script:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider smash)
{
    if (smash.gameObject.tag == "Environment")
    {
        // this prevents the bullet from going through
        // walls.
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    else if (smash.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        // teleporting the player back to the latest 
        // checkpoint.
        smash.gameObject.transform.position = GameManager.instance.checkpoint;

        // just to check whether the collision
        // is detecting or not.
        Debug.Log("Player died");

        // just for aesthetic. Probably no purpose in
        // bothering to destroy this gameObject.
        Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Getting the correct checkpoint out of the GameManager isn't the issue according to Unity's console. So what is the problem? Are there any more functions that I need share? The collisoin is definitely being detected, as "Player died" always shows up in my logs whenever he is hit by a bullet.

Comment: Did you try to print player position before and after teleporting? Are you sure that checkpoint is correct? You can print it as well

Comment: Yep, checkpoint is completely correct. I've verified it multiple times. I've since 'fixed' the issue. For some reason it teleports to the checkpoint on some occasions but ignores it on the others. Probably some nuance in the way taking variables from other scripts works.

Comment: In general rather use `CompareTag` which prevents typos from silently failing the check

Answer (score 0):

for collision purpose first add the following public variable to store the Player's the health:

```
public int health = 10;
```

To handle collisions, add the following methods:

```
void collidedWithEnemy(Enemy enemy) {
  // Enemy attack code
  if(health <= 0) {
    // Todo 
  }
}

void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) {
    Enemy enemy = col.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>();
    collidedWithEnemy(enemy);
}
```

And lastly for the checkpoint load system, first save the player data about it’s position using binary format like this:

```
public int level;
public int health;
public float[] position;

public playerData (PlayerCollision player)
(

    level = player.level;
    health = player.health;

    position = new float[3];

    position[0] = player.transform.position.x;
    position[1] = player.transform.position.y;
    position[2] = player.transform.position.z;

)
```

for the ckeckpoint system system to be loaded and initiated use this:

```
using System.Runtime.Serilization.Formatters.Binary;

    public static class CheckpointSystem
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.fun";
        FileStream stream = new Filestream(path, FileMode.Create);

        playerData data = new playerData(player);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
           
    }

    public static playerData LoadPlayer()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.fun";

        if(File.Exist(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new Filestream(path, FileMode.Open);

            playerData data = formatter.Deserlize(stream) as playerData;
            stream.Close();

            return data;
        }

        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("saved file not found in " + path);
            return null;
        
        }
        
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: [**STOP using `BinaryFormatter` at all!**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) Rather use JSON, XML or other formats

Comment: I wasn’t aware of the threats, thanks for informing.